# ioper commands isub idiv order in java virtualmachine

Tags: compiler-construction, jvm, vm-implementation

when looking at ioper commands imul and iadd are obvious but if I have:

sipush 9
sipush 3
sipush 4

the stack will look like

4
3
9

if the next one is isub do i subtract 4 from 3? or 3 from 4

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the instructions are defined in [section 6.5 of the JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5). In particular [isub](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.isub) is defined like this:

> #### Operand Stack
>
> ..., value1, value2 →
>
> ..., result
>
> #### Description
>
> Both value1 and value2 must be of type `int`. The values are popped from the operand stack. The `int` result is `value1 - value2`. The result is pushed onto the operand stack.

The notation `..., value1, value2` means that `value2` is on the top of the stack and `value1` is the one below that (and the rest of the stack is denoted as `...` because `isub` does not touch it).

So in your example it'd be `3 - 4` because `value1 = 3` and `value2 = 4`.